How do I create a scheduled report for Overdue Invoices
I would like to create a report that I can schedule weekly/daily to view any overdue invoices.  This is not the sales tab, since that is manual.
Why are the "filters" so limited on each report?
I also want to see not the "due date" but how "how many days" are overdue in a column.  How do I dod that?
I looked at two reporsts:

I looked at the "A/R Aging Summary Report", but I cannot remove the "Current" column (outstanding but not overdue invoices).

I looked at the "Invoices List Report", but I cannot find a filter for "Overdue" status for the "A/R Paid", which is only "Paid" and "Unpaid".


